# Why does this PHP statement strip 7's unexpectedly?

Tags: php, substr, strpos

I would love a fresh pair of eyes looking at my problem which is driving me mad. Any help would be appreciated.

From just 2 lines of PHP code im trying to strip the first '44' if a user enters it at the start of there phone number:

```
    $telephone = '44789562356';
    $telephone = str_replace(' ','',$telephone);
    $telephone = str_replace('+44','0',$telephone);
if(strpos($telephone,"44")==0){
        $telephone = substr($telephone,2);
        $telephone = '0'.$telephone;
    }
```

Why is it that it strips '7's from all the phone numbers?

Comment: Well, first of all, your `strpos` check should be using `===` not `==` (the code inside your if statement will run if `44` doesn't appear in the phone number at all).

Comment: Apart from comment & answer. It is working fine already. http://codepad.org/ai61PShL

Comment: It doesn't strip the 7's for me. When I run it I get `0789562356`.

Comment: The 7 would be removed if the input were `'+44789562356'`, because of the point that Colin Morelli made.

Comment: If strpos() doesn't find anything it returns -1 rather than 0 was what I generally understood

Comment: No, it returns `false` if it doesn't find anything. And `false == 0`, but not `false === 0`.

Comment: @JohnPeterson it does in other languages with strict typing, but not in PHP.

Comment: I have tried your code and for me its working ok. The 7 stills there in the correct place having this as a result: `0789562356`.

Answer (score 0):

Like Colin commented, you need to use a strict comparison `===` on the return from `strpos()` since it returns `false` if the substring is not found, and `0` if it's at the beginning of the string and `false == 0` is true, and `false === 0` is false.

Alternatively, you can use regular expressions to specify matching only at the beginning of the string like so:

```
if( preg_match('/^44/', $telephone) ) { ... }
```

Or do the replacment with it:

```
preg_replace('/^44/', '0', $telephone);
```

Your code can be simplified to the following:

```
$telephone = '+44-789 56-2356 ask for larry';
$telephone = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$telephone); // remove all non-numeric characters
$telephone = preg_replace('/^44/','0',$telephone);
echo $telephone;
// output: 0789562356
```